# password_verify hash not matching password

Tags: php, mysqli, php-password-hash

I have generated a password hash using the code below:

```
$hash = password_hash("test", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

I then store it in the database using a 255 char.

Then I try to do the comparator to test the login and it fails. It only lets me login using a hash I have just generated a few lines before, not one stored in the database.

```
<?php 

//Database connection
require 'database.php';

//Handle logins
if ($_POST['login'])
{
    //Receive the login attempt
    $login_email = $_POST['login_email'];
    $login_password = $_POST['login_password'];

    //Get the password hash
    if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1"))
    {
        $statement->bind_param("s", $login_email);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();

        //Does the account exist?
        if ($statement->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $statement->bind_result($hash);
            $statement->fetch();

            //echo $login_password;
            echo $hash."<br>";
            //$hash = password_hash("test", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            //echo $hash."<br>";

            //Check the password hash
            if (password_verify($login_password, $hash))
            {
                echo '<br>Password is valid!';

                //Begin session
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "yellow";
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo '<br>Invalid password.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Account doesn't exist warning
        }

        $statement->free_result();
        $statement->close();
    }
}

//Handle new registrations
if ($_POST['register'])
{
    //Receive the register attempt
    $register_email = $_POST['register_email'];
    $register_password_one = $_POST['register_password_one'];
    $register_password_two = $_POST['register_password_two'];

    //Check if email is already taken
    if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1"))
    {
        $statement->bind_param("s", $register_email);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();

        //Does the account exist?
        if ($statement->num_rows > 0)
        {
            //Account already exists warning
        }
        else
        {
            //Create the account
            if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (email, password) VALUES (?,?)"))
            {
                //Create bycrypt hash of password
                $hash = password_hash($register_password_one, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                //Insert new account
                $statement->bind_param("ss", $register_email, $hash);
                $statement->execute();
                $account_id = $statement->insert_id;
                $statement->close();

                //Begin session
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "yellow";
            }
        }
        $statement->free_result();
        $statement->close();
    }
}

//Handle logout
if ($_POST['logout'])
{
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}

?>
```

password hash in database: $2y$10$xDnZIjzw8h.9utp3qyRlxezPd8jmK9k6Z5JuoVtooOpkPCBd.n6W6
password hash that is just generated (works): $2y$10$tolDQdeTQrTio8IJ0Wi9AuHN5Km28pSB5kUh5qfkdkOsDXP295H1K

I am not an expert with hashing. Just trying to follow the latest recommendations. Could someone tell me why the hash is different to the one in the database?

Comment: `$login_password` = test?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑunfortunately yes

Comment: Please include more code. This *should* work. Have you debugged all variables involved, to confirm their values are as expected (post the values then)?

Comment: Make sure you're not pre-hashing and that the column's length is long enough to accomodate the hash and is VARCHAR.

Comment: Re "why is the hash different every time": that's on purpose due to the use of a randomly generated salt, whose purpose is to make each hash unique. Don't worry about that.

Comment: Ok changed to varchar(255) doesn't seem to make a difference. Pre-hashing how. I just hash it in the register code and place in database. Exact same code as above. It works fine on a single php file execution, but if I execute it separately it doesn't work.

Comment: You're going to need to show us more code then, as previously stated.

Comment: The problem is that the first hash (the one in your database) is invalid. Full stop. You need to store a valid hash in the database in order to successfully verify it.

Comment: Ok I have added all the code. Sorry was just reluctant to share it all for security things you know....

Comment: @clapas how can I make the one stored in database valid? :)

Comment: I ran the `password_verify()` function with the first hash and it returns false. Just delete it and store a valid one, e.g. the second one you provide.

Comment: *"Sorry was just reluctant to share it all for security things you know"* - We/I understand. Just as long as you don't share your (DB/server) login information and that it only contains "code", then there's no danger Amy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the hash generated is different every time
- pass plain text to the password_verify() function... see below

```
$originalPassword = password_hash("THE_PASSWORD", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// This will produce something like (taken form above) 
$2y$10$tolDQdeTQrTio8IJ0Wi9AuHN5Km28pSB5kUh5qfkdkOsDXP295H1K
```

// When verifying this
if(password_verify("THE_PASSWORD", $passwordFromDatabase['password'])){
echo "Success";
}else{
echo "Fail";
}

Comment: I am a bit worried to use PASSWORD_DEFAULT because what if they change the way that PASSWORD_DEFAULT is calculated to some new encryption. Then all my users would lose the ability to log in?

Comment: its my understanding that this will automatically change when stronger algo's get introduced and it will recognise passwords made with a previous algo

Comment: the start of the algo is the identifier in the case above it would be $2y$

Comment: yes I did notice that and wonder what it was. That makes sense to me now! Let me just test this to see if it works :)